# Python - program crashes every 60 seconds making new requests in a while loop

Tags: python

I have a script running every 60 seconds making a request using rest API:

```
     def get_conn():
        try:
          ms = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=xxx)
          current_time = time.mktime(ms.timetuple())
          ms = datetime.now()
          current_time2 = time.mktime(ms.timetuple())
          api_Url = "xxxxxx".format(int(xxxx), int(xxxx))
          conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("xxxxx")
          conn.request("GET", api_Url, payload, headers)
          print('Getting response...')
          res = conn.getresponse()
          data = res.read()
          data = data.decode("utf-8")
          data = json.loads(data)
          return data
        except Exception as e:
          handle_crash(e)

    def handle_crash(e):
        print('Restarting in 60 seconds ' + str(e))
        time.sleep(60)  # Restarts the script after 60 seconds
        start()

    def start():

        while True:

            data = get_conn()
            time.sleep(60)


start()
```

And the output:

```
    Getting response...
    Restarting in 60 seconds Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
    Getting response...
    Restarting in 60 seconds Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
    Getting response...
    Restarting in 60 seconds Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
    Getting response...
    Restarting in 60 seconds Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
    Getting response...
    Restarting in 60 seconds Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I am not showing the output of the first request as the first request is successful, but after the first request immediately after 60 seconds, the handle_crash(e) gets called every time.

When I test this calling start() every 1 second I get a few requests back but after 5 or 6 requests the script crashes, so I tried running the script every 60 seconds.

Can someone see where the script is going wrong?

Comment: Yes, I can: somewhere between `try` and `except` an exception "Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)" is raised. If you just let the exception happen instead of handling it you will see more details.

Comment: That error indicates that you're getting an empty response, so `json.loads(data)` fails.

Comment: i know that the data which is json is returning empty, but like i said the first request does return data, im just not showing that data in the question

Comment: Maybe the second request doesn't return data?

Comment: So you're probably running into a rate limiter. I guess the 60 second sleep isn't enough.

Comment: BTW, the `requests` module is much easier to use than the `http` module.

Comment: but when i run every 1 second about 5 6 requests comes back but crashes also

Comment: The endpoint could be designed in the way it accepts one request per user/session on every 10s, for example.

Comment: As a side note, your code is unnecessarily recursive, and will overflow the stack after too many exceptions. There's no reason to call `start` during the exception handling when you're already in a `while True` loop.

Comment: Try printing the data before you convert it into json so you can asure that the data is actually what you are expecting or something different. And, as mkrieger1 said, remove the exception handling and let the program crash for a better error message

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps as the full answer, but getting a response from you guys was very helpful especially from @Barmar who said use the request, after I replaced the import http.client with import requests and used:

```
r = requests.get("https://xxxxx" + api_Url, auth=auth)
data = r.json()
```

Worked like a charm and the script never crashes.

Sorry @Barmar I clicked upvote twice and cant upvote you again by mistake.

So I upvoted everyone.